# How to JSON serialize class derived from Web Control class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Does anyone know how to serialize a custom control to JSON that is derived from another web control. I keep getting the error that the base class is not serializable. Here is the code for the derived class

```
public class BaseWidget : CompositeControl
{
    protected Label _lblHeader;
    protected Button _editButton;
    protected HtmlInputHidden _idField;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unique identified that identifies this widget
    /// </summary>

    public int ControlID
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            int i = -1;
            int.TryParse(_idField.Value, out i);
            return i;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            _idField.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow the user to edit the widget
    /// </summary>
    public bool AllowEdit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return _lblHeader.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            _lblHeader.Text = value;
        }
    }



    public string CallbackFunction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    protected Panel Header
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Main Control of the widget
    /// </summary>
    protected Panel Content
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected Panel Edit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected Panel Body
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The tag that the control is associated with
    /// </summary>
    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get
        {
            return HtmlTextWriterTag.Li;
        }
    }


    public BaseWidget()
    {
        this.ControlID = 0;
    }}
```

I actually don't even need to serialize any of the attributes in the base class. I just need the control id and the title associated serialized. Is there any way of doing this when Web Control is not serializable. I tried DataContractJsonSerializer and JavascriptSerializer with no luck because the WebControl class is not serializable.

Answer (score 1):

On the DataContractJsonSerializer you can define a surrogate which is serialized in place of the control (search for IDataContractSurrogate for more information). But if all you need is to serialize those two properties, then it'll likely be simpler for you to simply create a data class (DTO?) with those properties and serialize it instead.

```
public class BaseWidgetDTO
{
    public int ControlID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```